# How to get router.push to work correctly in this example?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

For the following code, after the server returns 200, router.push doesn't actually do anything

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errHidden, setErrHidden] = useState(true)
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch("/editor")
  }, [])

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`/api/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log('pushing editor');
      router.push("/editor");
      console.log(router)
    } else {
      setErrHidden(false)
    }
  };

  return (<Component>...</Component>)
```

It does log the first console.log statement correctly. The second one prints out the router object but has no evidence that the `push` function was called. Not seeing any errors or warnings in the console or terminal either.

Comment: Spitballing here but perhaps you have to resolve that async function before pushing to the router conditionally based on the responses status code

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Could you provide a codesanbox example (or similiar) replicating the issue?